# Syntax Highlighting Excluding Part of Match from Coloring?

Tags: textmate

For the syntax highlighting for a language, is there a way to exclude part of the matching used for selection from the actualy highlighting. I want to select variable/function usages such as ".someVariable" but I don't want the "." to actually get highlighted. Just the "someVariable" part. But I need the "." to be part of the matching.

What I have in the tmLanguage file for the specific selection:

```
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\b\.([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>variable.language.mylang</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: BTW, have you managed to make this one work? I wonder if `<string>(?<=\.)\b([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b</string>`  works. Also, probably, `<string>(?<=\.)\b([_a-zA-Z][-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)\b</string>`  will be more correct as function names can only start with letters or underscore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `captures = {…}` to define names (“scopes”) only for parts of the match. This will work:

```
{ patterns = (
  { match = '\b\.([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b';
    captures = {
      1 = { name = "variable.language.mylang"; } ;
    };
  },
);}
```